# Browser Sync with php files only works when phpinfo() is in the file

Tags: php, browser-sync

I'm using Browser Sync to automatically refresh my page when a php file changes. I was trouble shooting why it wasn't working so I had `phpinfo()` in the file. OPcache was enabled, I disabled it and refreshing began to work.

But after I deleted `phpinfo()` from the file browser refreshing doesn't happen. If I add it back in it works again.

I'm using [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead) as my VM.

Any idea what might be going on? So weird.

Comment: Could be the browser's buffer. Try placing a lot of whitespaces at the end

Comment: @toraman thanks, but it didn't work

Comment: By automatically refreshing, do you mean displaying or handling data as php prints? Can you post a piece of code?